# migration from server 2008 to 2012 R2 using Robocopy

Tags: robocopy

I have old file server running Server 2008 and I have new file server that will be replaced it running 2012 R2. They're both under the same AD .

I have  copied one share already using: robocopy \source\share \destination\share /mir /sec /secfix

It applied permissions to the root share but not the subfolders, which is an issue. How do I copy permissions and have them stick to every subfolder/file under the main share?

Also, is there a way to duplicate the data drive entirely? Instead of going share by share, if I want to copy the entire contents of D drive on source to E drive on destination, along with permissions, can I use robocopy to do this?

Comment: Did you run Robocopy more than once against this data and possibly add the `/sec` switch after it had already run once?

Comment: no , I will try this and feed you back

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you try it but rather that you might have done it before and that may have explained why it didn't work. I'll get back to you with some ideas tonight after I've had time to think about it!

Comment: thanks Mr Ethernet for your help and I was hoping to get a solution in the same week of the  problem ,  as an answer to your question  "no I didn't do it before "  but my problem solved by a copying program that has been suggested by an expert , this program called gs richcopy 360 , it also solve the problem of long path names that we faced before . and also I will mention the solution that I received later after 4 weeks

Answer (score 2):

I have this answer and I think it is free and Logical :
 you don't need to use Robocopy to migrate files in a file server unless you are sure that account have access to all the files and folders.

The alternatives are 
  -  use MS storage Migration services    or 
  - use a file backup like Veeam Agent for Windows "free".
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-migration-service/overview

but as I am mentioning in comments I switched to copying program and it is doing well till now

Answer (score 1):

I switched to Microsoft Storage Migration Services when Microsoft released it, and I left `RoboCopy` for file server migrations.

Try to install a trial of server and spin up Windows Admin Center, then install the SMS role and follow the wizard. with File Server Migrations using SMS, I haven’t had any issues until now.

For more detail see [Step by Step: Migrate Your File Servers with Storage Migration Service in Windows Server 2019](https://www.google.com/amp/s/charbelnemnom.com/2018/11/step-by-step-migrate-your-file-servers-with-storage-migration-service-in-windows-server-2019/%3Famp), and for the `gsrichcopy360` program that you mentioned in comments, it's great.  We have used this program for three years in my company for copying issues.